# How do I add a key to the app.config file

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, oledbconnection

I am new to automation and I am trying to get data from an Excel sheet using OLEDB, I get an errror saying "OLEDB Exception : Invalid argument" in C#

So, One of the answers to a similar question suggest that I add a key to the app.config file for my test data. Now I am not familiar with the .config files

So, I need help with the key or any other solutions to my problem will do

Here is my code:

```
{
    class ExcelDataAccess
    {
        public static string TestDataFileConnection()
        {
            var fileName = 
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"Path\DataSet.xlsx"];
            var con = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
Source = {0}; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'", fileName);
            return con;
        }

        public static UserData GetTestData(string keyName)
        {
            using (var connection = new 
  OleDbConnection(TestDataFileConnection()))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var query = string.Format("select * from [DataSet$] where 
  key='{0}'", keyName);
                  var value = connection.Query<UserData>
(query).FirstOrDefault();
                connection.Close();
                return value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use ExcelDataReader - https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader

```
using ExcelDataReader;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace Test.Data.Excel
{
    public class Reader
    {
        public static IEnumerable<object[]> Read(string filePath)
        {
            using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                {
                    var count = reader.FieldCount;
                    do
                    {
                        var list = new List<object>();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            list.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                        }
                        yield return list.ToArray();

                    } while (reader.NextResult());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me your "ExcelReaderFactory" class

Comment: Get that class from nuget

Comment: I have found another way,Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code to import data from Excel sheet.
"openFileDialog1_FileOk" is a Button

```
Private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
            {
                string filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
                string header = rbHeaderYes.Checked ? "YES" : "NO";
                string conStr, sheetName;

                conStr = string.Empty;
                switch (extension)
                {

                    case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                        conStr = string.Format(Excel03ConString, filePath, header);
                        break;

                    case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                        conStr = string.Format(Excel07ConString, filePath, header);
                        break;
                }

                //Get the name of the First Sheet.
                using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        DataTable dtExcelSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                        sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }

                //Read Data from the First Sheet.
                using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                    {
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                        {
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            con.Open();
                            oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                            oda.Fill(dt);
                            sampleDatatable = dt;
                            con.Close();
                            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;



                            //dataGridView2.DataSource = Headers;

                        }
                    }
                }


 }
```